# SQL: How do I count the number of unanswered (backlog) emails on each day based on incoming day and duration until answer?

Tags: sql, datetime

In SQL, I have a table called emails. It contains a column called StartDTE (a datetime) and a duration in seconds. The StartDTE is when the email entered the system, the duration is the time until it is answered. I need to create a table of backlogs. This table has a column of unique dates and then a column with the counts of emails in backlog. An email is counted in the backlog for each day between its startDTE and the day it is answered AFTER 9AM (beginning of working day). So, if an email is answered before 9am on its last day, then it is not counted in backlog. If it is answered after 9am on a day, then it is still counted as backlog for that day.

I am fairly new to SQL so I have no idea how to tackle this issue in the most efficient way.

EDIT: I am using TSQL in Microsoft sql server management studio.

In the example data, rows 1-7 should all be counted in the backlog of 2020-01-08. Row 8 should be counted in the backlog of 2020-01-10, 2020-01-11, 2020-01-12 and 2020-01-13.

[Example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SggMg.png)

Comment: What dialect of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.)? Some of the syntax for handling datetimes can differ between dialects.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.